# .NET: Storing Datatable with parametrized stored procedure using ODBC

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable, odbc, dataadapter

Stuck filling a datatable. Is it about filling the datatable?, Is it about passing parameters?, is it about a procedure with out sys_refcursor? Tried this:

```
public DataTable ConnectAndQuery(string layerName, decimal idElemento, string idElementoString, string conexion)
{
    Logger.Debug("App_Code/ConexionBD.cs: using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; + conexion ");
    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conexion))
    {
        try
        {
            using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter())
            {
                da.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand("{ call PKG_GEONET_REPORTS.GET_ORDINARY_CLIENT(?, ?, ?) }", conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //da.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("client_in", idElemento.ToString());
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("layer_in", layerName);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("client_data", ParameterDirection.Output);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "data");

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["data"];

                /*foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }*/
                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
    public DataTable ConnectAndQuery(string layerName, decimal idElemento, string idElementoString, string conexion)
    {
        Logger.Debug("App_Code/ConexionBD.cs: using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; + conexion ");
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conexion))
        {
            try
            {
                using (OdbcCommand Command = new OdbcCommand("{ call PKG_GEONET_REPORTS.GET_ORDINARY_CLIENT() }", conn))
                {
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("client_in", idElemento.ToString());
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("layer_in", layerName);
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("client_data", ParameterDirection.Output);
                    using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(Command))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no error message, my app couldn't show the result, I'm just seeing a blank screen.

my conexion string is:

```
"Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};...;"
```

and my stored procededure is:

```
PROCEDURE GET_ORDINARY_CLIENT (client_in IN varchar2, layer_in IN varchar2, client_data OUT SYS_REFCURSOR );
```

Comment: Could you add the first lines of the StoredProcedure GET_ORDINARY_CLIENT?

Comment: I just added the procedure definition Sr.

Comment: I suggest to use the first example where the parameters are added in the order expected by the sp and change the ReturnValue option with the Output option (a parameter passed to the stored procedure is not a ReturnValue but an IN or OUT parameter and yours seems to be an Output parameter)

Comment: Should I assume there is no method to accomplish this using ODBC?. I found nothing on Internet.

Comment: Why? Did you try using ParameterDirection.Output instead of ReturnValue?

Comment: I tried both. Just for testing

Comment: You can also try to remove the _{ call_ and the closing _}_ in the creation of the command. Leave just the name of the SP: Remove also the _(?,?,?)_

Comment: I'm not that familiar with oracle, most of my experience is with MS Sql Server, but from your code I assume that the `client_data` is an out parameter that contains a resultset, and you try to populate `dt` from that data. Why not simply use `select` in the stored procedure (since that's what the dataAdapter is expecting...) Also, why use OdbcClient when you have [OracleClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: My client_data is an out sys_refcursor and contains a multiple select statement. Using ODBC because I have many connections based on that and I cant change those.